# Name for 1-e and 1+e terms?

Tags: orbital-elements

In several equations of orbital elements (such as the determination of true anomaly from mean anomaly), the terms 1-*e* and 1+*e* appear. These are the ratios of the orbital periapsis and apoapsis to the semi-major axis, but do the ratios themselves have names?

Comment: $e$ is called eccentricity in that case. But that's probably not, what you were asking for. Not sure, if there are terms for $1-e$ and $ 1+e $.

Comment: Are you looking for names for $1-e$ and $1+e$, or $\frac{1-e}{1+e}$ and $\frac{1+e}{1-e}$?

Comment: The former pair.

Answer (score 4):

As the commenter states, $e$ is indeed called the orbital eccentricity. If you add a radial scale length (e.g., semi-major axis) to both of those values the $1-e$ describes the periapsis (closest approach of orbit) and the $1+e$ apoapsis (furthest) of an elliptical orbit. They don't have a specific special name, as they are dimensionless measures, but can be quite useful in determining the orbit of planets and other Keplerian systems.

Periapsis:
$$
r_{p}=a(1-e)
$$
Apoapsis:
$$
r_{a}=a(1+e)
$$

Perhaps the could be named the maximum radial eccentricity and minimum radial eccentricity, if you needed to describe these parameters in a report or class homework etc.

Comment: I was trying to choose variable names for those terms in a computer program.

Comment: e_p and e_a should be sufficient.

Comment: $1-e$ determined as $r_p/a$ would be the "semi-major axis normalized periapsis distance" but I guess this is a bit clumsy...